# Eclipse "The spelling service is not installed."

Tags: eclipse

I have installed eclipse , and install software for pydev 
when i want to change the character, i found the spelling service is not install.

no idea to enable this service , it seems default setting

how can i enable this service

eclipse
Version: Neon Release (4.6.0)
Build id: 20160613-1800

thanks

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a bizarre quirk of history, the most used spell checking engine is part of the Java Tools (there might be one in the C/C++ Tools as well). You'll need to install those from the Neon update site.